# If else statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables :

- Town
- Department
- Region
- Country

A `department` have a foreign key to `region` and a `region` to `Country`

A `town` have 3 foreign key to the others tables but only one of them should be filled, the others have to be null.
This is because you can reached the town's `Country` with its `departement` or `region` by following foreign keys.

Now i want to make a SQL query that return me all the towns with their department, region, country (if set).
And the problem is that i cannot make differents joins based on which town's FK is set..

How to get that work ?

Comment: You could use a `LEFT JOIN` between tables; if you aren't familiar with this syntax, Jeff Atwood has a great introduction here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Could you share your data model on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)? That makes it easier to understand your question.

Comment: I've tried using `CASE` but it can't be used to make differents join base on result, it return only a value. The data model is more complex than my example, in fact, i have to fetch translations of department, region, and country too.. (i'm making the model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT …
FROM Town
LEFT JOIN Department ON Department.id = Town.department
LEFT JOIN Region ON Region.id = COALESCE(Town.region, Department.region)
LEFT JOIN Country ON Country.id = COALESCE(Town.country, Region.country)
```

`COALESCE` takes the first non-`NULL` value from its arguments. So in this case, values from `Town` override other settings. As you state that a town which has a region reference won't have a department reference, only one of them should ever be non-`NULL`, so order does not matter if your data is as you say. The `LEFT JOIN`s ensure that you get `NULL` values for tables which have no match. If all you need from the country is its id, you might instead omit the last join and include the `COALESCE` into the values you select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an query to display the value.

```
select town.*,Department.*,Region.*,Country.* from town,Department,Region,Country where town.Dept_Id = Department.Dept and town.Region_Id = Region.Region_Id and town.Country_Id = Country.Countr_Id and Department.Region_Id = Region.Region_Id and Region.Country_Id = Country.Country_Id
```

Instead of this you can user Left Join Query. This query will take much more execute time. Left join query

```
select * from town left join Department ON Department.id = Town.department left join Region ON Region.id = coalesce (Town.region, Department.region) left join Country ON Country.id = coalesce (Town.country, Region.country)
```